# Choose between C++ top-level functions of the same name

Tags: c++

My C++ project `huzzah`  has a top-level header `include/huzzah.h` for defining two functions
`do_this` and `do_that`. I have multiple implementations of those functions in `src/thing1.cpp` and `src/thing2.cpp`. Given the following unit test, how can I specify either to use the do_this or the do_that implementations of the functions? Perhaps in the `huzzah/CMakeLists.txt`, or via the `main` args?

```
#include "huzzah.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto a = do_this;
    auto b = do_that;
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

(I don't want to make these into Thing1 and Thing2 classes.)

Comment: "I have multiple implementations" - U wot? What ever happened to the one definition rule?! How does this thing even compile?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, it sounds like you broke the [one-definition-rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: You must decide at link time which implementation to link. It's not possible to link multiple definitions for the same declarations.

Comment: You can't do that -- you can have separate implementations for separate compilation units, but you'll be able to only link to one of them at a time.

You can have the same test code, and two separate test targets in your `CMakeLists.txt` which would depend on the one or the other.

Comment: Do you want to use both from the same executable?

Comment: Do you want to do this at runtime or compile time?

Comment: I imagine at runtime. Say that `main` is in a script that's compiled to `run_huzzah`. How could I do something from the command line like `./run_huzzah thing2` to specify the functions should be from `thing2.cpp`?

Comment: And I do not wish to use both from the same executable @Slava.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: Compile them both to shared library and dynamically load one based on parameter. You can load them both and resolve symbols manually.

Comment: @Slava ubuntu 16.04. Would you be able to provide some code to show how to "compile them both to shared library and dynamically load one based on parameter. You can load them both and resolve symbols manually"?

Comment: Might I ask why you want to do this in the first place? And why it can't be done using macro conditionals, for example? (Still not sure why one would want this in any case)

Comment: Can not help my self, but seems like a strange design, like something that should be designed like a base class with implementations for do_this and for do_that overriding some virtual method. Then the question would be rendered meaningless because there would not be any language conflict or issue and deciding between implementations would be done very easily without the magic of dynamic loading etc. I like to help, but not to help others to impale themselves:).

Comment: @Aziuth I didn't rule out macro conditionals as a possible solution. What would that look like?

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain I mean, why not have it as simple as `void do_this() { #if STANDARDWAY (code of first implementation) #else (code of second implementation) #endif }`, with STANDARDWAY or however you want to call it being set in the Makefile, or project file if you use QT.

Comment: Yes that is simple, but where would `STANDARDWAY` be defined? I'm building with a CMakeLists.txt, and I don't think it can be defined there. I would prefer not having `STANDARDWAY = true` at the top of the executable that the user would have to go in and change manually -- setting from the command line is much preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 shared libraries for each cpp file (in cmake):

```
add_library(thing1 SHARED src/thing1.cpp)
add_library(thing2 SHARED src/thing2.cpp)
```

then load them dynamically using dlopen/dlsym (do not link your app with those libs):

```
using do_this_f = decltype(&do_this);

auto handle = dlopen( "libthing1.so", RTLD_LAZY );
auto do_this_1 = reinterpret_cast<do_this_f>( dlsym( handle, "do_this" ) );
do_this_1(); // calling do_this from libthing1.so
```

of course you need to add error handling, proper path to lib and so on

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks for the suggestion :) If that `main` is in a script that's compiled to `run_huzzah`, how could I do something from the command line like `./run_huzzah thing2` to specify the functions should be from `thing2.cpp`? Would it be parsing `argc` and `argv` w/ a switch-case (or if-else) block that then sets your `handle`? What would that look like?

Comment: As you can see "libthing1.so" passed as a string at runtime so it is up to you how you build that string through `argv` or whatever way.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than it seems:

```
#include "huzzah.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto a = do_this();
    auto b = do_that();
    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}

g++ -o test1 testmain.cpp src/thing1.cpp
g++ -o test2 testmain.cpp src/thing2.cpp
```